# Doctor pulled to the future to save a leader in a time when medicine is banned

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I read it back in the 80s so it must be older than 1985. The plot goes like this.

A doctor gets transferred to the future. He materialises in the middle of the road and almost gets killed. He finds out that medicine has been banned.
The group that transported him finds him and tell him that they brought him to the future so that he may save the life of their leader. The leader has been stabbed to the heart with a dart, and frozen until they can find a doctor somewhere in time and bring him back to save the leader. But the leader's condition is irreversible and they decide to go back in time to the moment of the stabbing. But in a weird turn of events the doctor is forced to stab the leader.

Comment: Is "hart" a typo for "heart"?

Answer (score 3):

Philip K Dick's novel *Doctor Futurity* (1960), expanded from the novella "Time Pawn" in *Thrilling Wonder Stories*, Summer 1954, which is available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Thrilling_Wonder_Stories_v44n01_1954-Summer#page/n67/mode/2up).

The group the Doctor is brought to help were Indians who were using time travel to reclaim America for themselves. At one point the Doctor is exiled to the planet Mars but is rescued in the flight to the Red Planet by time travel trickery.

One other thing when he first materializes in the future the reason he is nearly run down, is because the driver thought if he was on the road he wanted to be run down. The future is moderately dystopian.

Comment: @user14111 Glad you could find "Time Pawn". That's a great help. Gives the OP a chance to catch up with it.

Comment: @user14111 That's more than fine. I'm very grateful for your generosity and consideration. Thank you very much.